# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined inside React component used as child inside another parent component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, undefined, typeerror

FundraiserScreen.js

```
// import necessary stuffs and components;
// import Fundraiser component;
const Children = ({ loading, error, fundraiser }) => {
if (loading) // return and show skeleton loading html
if (!error) return <Fundraiser fundraiser={fundraiser} isCard={false} />
return // container with error message

const FundraiserScreen = ({ match }) => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const fundraiserDetails = useSelector((state) => state.fundraiserDetails);
const { loading, error, fundraiser } = fundraiserDetails;
useEffect(() => {
dispatch(listFundraiserDetails(match.params.id));
}, [dispatch, match]);

return (
// some HTML markups
<Children loading={loading} error={error} fundraiser={fundraiser} />
// end HTML markups
);

Children.propTypes = {
loading: PropTypes.bool,
error: PropTypes.bool,
fundraiser: PropTypes.shape({
    _id: PropTypes.string,
    image: PropTypes.string,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    shortDescription: PropTypes.string,
    description: PropTypes.string,
    collected: PropTypes.number,
    goal: PropTypes.number,
    donors: PropTypes.number,
    organizer: PropTypes.shape({
      name: PropTypes.string,
    }),
  }).isRequired,
};

FundraiserScreen.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
  }),
};
```

HomeScreen.js

```
// import necessary stuffs and components;
// import Fundraiser component;
const Children = ({ loading, error, fundraisers }) => {
if (loading) // return and show skeleton loading html
if (!error) return fundraisers.map((fundraiser) => (
// some HTML markups
<Fundraiser fundraiser={fundraiser} isCard />
// end HTML markups
));
return // container with error message

const HomeScreen = () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const fundraiserList = useSelector((state) => state.fundraiserList);
const { loading, error, fundraisers } = fundraiserList;
useEffect(() => {
dispatch(listFundraisers());
}, [dispatch]);

return (
// some HTML markups
<Children loading={loading} error={error} fundraisers={fundraisers} />
// end HTML markups
);

Children.propTypes = {
loading: PropTypes.bool,
error: PropTypes.string,
fundraisers: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
};
```

Fundraiser.js

```
// import necessary stuff and components
const Fundraiser = ({ fundraiser, isCard }) => {
 const {
 _id, image, title, shortDescription, description,
 collected = 0, goal = 0,
donors, organizer: { name },} = fundraiser;

if (isCard) {
return (
// some HTML markups
// am able to access {name} simply by console.log or inside any HTML element
// end HTML markups
);
}
return (
// some HTML markups
// unable to access {name} neither by console.log or inside any HTML element
// end HTML markups
);
};

Fundraiser.propTypes = {
fundraiser: PropTypes.shape({
_id: PropTypes.string,
image: PropTypes.string,
title: PropTypes.string,
shortDescription: PropTypes.string,
description: PropTypes.string,
collected: PropTypes.number,
goal: PropTypes.number,
donors: PropTypes.number,
organizer: PropTypes.shape({
  name: PropTypes.string,
}),
}).isRequired,
isCard: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};
```

These are the components. I am using react ^17.0.2, react-redux ^7.2.4, redux ^4.1.0, redux-devtools-extension ^2.13.9 and redux-thunk ^2.3.0 for global state management related to fundraiser. Backend is being served from node.js server. I am unable to fix the issue please suggest me some workaround. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests looks like your `fundraizer.organizer` is undefined and your trying to access `name` from undefined.

This may be because your value of `fundraizer` might be an `{}` or `null` or `undefined` . To prevent your app from breaking you can guard your values.

Pass default values

```
const Children = ({ loading, error, fundraiser = {} }) => {
```

Guard the values by providing default args

```
const {
 _id, image, title, shortDescription, description,
 collected = 0, goal = 0,
donors, organizer } = fundraiser || {};

const { name = '' } = organizer || {};
```

Comment: the error was in this part of your code `organizer: { name }` . you were trying to destructure name from `organizer` which was undefined .

Comment: Hello Shyam, Thank you your solution solved my error.
Just one more question can you tell me what am I doing wrong with this way of destructuring : const { _id, image, title, shortDescription, description, collected = 0, goal = 0,donors, organizer:  {name = ' ' }, } = fundraiser;
This was my last attempt to solve the error before you helped me.
Also, why is that fundraizer.organizer is undefined because in both condition I am sending the same object the only difference being that one is an array of fundraisers and another is just a single fundraiser. Once, again thank you so much :)

Comment: and I was only getting error while sending the single fundraiser object.

Comment: ` organizer: {name = ' ' }` means that your organizer is an object and you are destructuring `name` from it . so you telling when there is name in `organizer` use it else use the empty string which is the default value . But this did not work because your `organizer` was not even an object . To check this you can console log and see what you have in the `fundraiser` object .

Comment: Thank you now I understood the destructuring part, but I am still confused why I was getting not getting error on accessing organizer.name when sending the fundraiser object from array with the help of array.map as opposed to sending it as a single object.

Comment: I just console logged the fundraiser object at the start of code block inside Fundraiser component but it was showing the organizer object with name property and value. I also did console logged in my HomeScreen and FundraiserScreen, the same output was shown. Still it is a mystery for me why I was getting any error.